# sending a beep through microphone input

Tags: c#, vb.net, microphone, audacity

Is a way of creating a program (either in C(+,++,#) or VB.net) that would be able to send a beep sound through the same line-in that is being used for audacity (not stereo mix)?

I am trying to make a way of syncing up audio and video from 2 different programs, in a similar way that a clapper bored works in the movies.

Would there be a way of using a sort of microphone enhancement that could be created because they affect the microphone input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're trying to implement something like http://www.singularsoftware.com/pluraleyes.html then?  I think the best way would be to write a VST/[LADSPA](http://www.ladspa.org/) plug-in for Audacity that inserts the beeps synced to a timecode stream (or whatever you're syncing to).

There's a neat little library called [VST.NET](http://vstnet.codeplex.com/) that allows you to write VST plug-ins in standard C#/VB.NET if you like.

Comment: yeah that sort of thing would work, my setup is using fraps to record video and stereo mix and then using audacity to record microphone, by making a beep on the microphone input and stereo mix would save ages of fiddling about trying to get it synced right